# How to save xml contained in javascript string via php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have xml page contents in a javascript string. I need to save this into my.xml in the server side using php. But i can't seem to pass the xml-content-string value via POST method. I tried file_get_contents and curl but figured out that's not what I want since I have my xml content in string format and not in a file.
Can anyone help me to save this string in javascript as proper xml content.

Thanks in advance

Pre

I am attaching my code below

Page1.php

```
  <form name = "frm_first" method = "POST">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "xml_string">
    ...............


<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
function getDataXML(){
 xmlString = chart.getDataXML();// This is where I get my xml data into the string
 document.frm_first.xml_string.value = xmlString;
 alert(xml_string); //Good
 document.frm_first.submit();
}
</script>
```

Page2.php //This is the page to which post is submitted.

```
    <?php
    echo print_r($_POST);//xml_string vaiable is empty. Other variables are getting displayed.
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $domtree->loadXML($_POST['xml_string']);// Error :empty string supplied as input
    $domtree->save("my.xml"); //Yes , I have access to the file.
?>
```

$_POST['xml_string'] is empty is my issue. Other variables are getting passed via POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be answering my own question, but thought that it  might be of use to someone else too.
 I did a  if array_key_exists('xml_string', $_POST)

```
<?php
if array-_key_exists('xml_string', $_POST) 
{
    echo print_r($_POST);
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $domtree->loadXML($_POST['xml_string']);
    $domtree->save("my.xml"); 
?>
```

and now $_POST variables are coming in properly.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the header with PHP did the trick when i tried to save a XML file:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xml");
```

But sending the XML should be possible as string. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I did not get any error message. The form field that contains the string is empty after passing via POST.

Comment: Form field ... can you output the $_POST Variable itself? I cant imagine that a string cant be send with $_POST. Maybe theres just an issue with your form, not with the POST.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it is. I have other form fields that are getting passed and printed in $_POST. This string that contains the xml content is not getting passed/printed.

Comment: Well, thats one of the weirdest errors ive ever seen, and ive seen a lot of shit in my life. Can you post the lines which contain the problem?

Comment: I have added my code in the original question. Was too big for the edit column. Thank you for going through.

Comment: `<form name = "frm_first" method = "POST">` Add this into it `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Could imagine that this is the problem.

Comment: Tried multipart/form-data. No luck!

Comment: jeeez this error is persistant. Can you upload your full code (php/html) on pastebin or somewhere else? Ill take a look at it when its lunch time, maybe i find something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45996/discussion-between-pre-and-y-u-no-work)